# Calling MethodBase's Invoke on a constructor (reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, invoke, methodbase

First of all, sorry if this has been asked before. I've done a pretty comprehensive search and found nothing quite like it, but I may have missed something.

And now to the question: I'm trying to invoke a constructor through reflection, with no luck. Basically, I have an object that I want to clone, so I look up the copy constructor for its type and then want to invoke it. Here's what I have:

```
public Object clone(Object toClone) {
     MethodBase copyConstructor = type.GetConstructor(
         new Type[] { toClone.GetType() });
     return method.Invoke(toClone, new object[] { toClone }); //&lt;-- doesn't work
}
```

I call the above method like so:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(new int[] { 0, 1, 2 });
List<int> clone = (List<int>) clone(list);
```

Now, notice the invoke method I'm using is `MethodBase`'s invoke. `ConstructorInfo` provides an invoke method that does work if invoked like this:

```
return ((ConstructorInfo) method).Invoke(new object[] { toClone });
```

However, I want to use `MethodBase`'s method, because in reality instead of looking up the copy constructor every time I will store it in a dictionary, and the dictionary contains both methods and constructors, so it's a `Dictionary<MethodBase>`, not `Dictionary<ConstructorInfo>`.
I could of course cast to `ConstructorInfo` as I do above, but I'd rather avoid the casting and use the `MethodBase` method directly. I just can't figure out the right parameters.

Any help? Thanks so much.

---

**EDIT**
Benjamin,
Thanks so much for your suggestions. I was actually doing exactly what you suggest in your second edit, except (and that's a big "except") my dictionary was  where

```
class ClonerMethod {

    public MethodBase method;
    public bool isConstructor;

    ...

    public Object invoke(Object toClone) {
        return isConstructor ?
            ((ConstructorInfo) method).Invoke(new object[] { toClone }) : //<-- I wanted to avoid this cast
            method.Invoke(toClone, null);
    }

}
```

And then I called `ClonerMethod`'s `invoke` on what I found in the dictionary. I didn't add the code the deals with all that because the answer I was looking for was just how to call Invoke on a `ConstructorInfo` using `MethodBase`'s `Invoke` method, so I didn't want to add unnecessary info and too much code for you guys to read through. However, I like your use of `Func<,>` much MUCH better, so I'm switching to that. Also making the `Clone` method generic is a nice addition, but in my case the caller doesn't know the type of the object, so I'll keep it non-generic instead.

I didn't know about `Func<,>`, and if I knew about the lambda operator I had forgotten (I hadn't really needed something like this before), so I've actually learnt a lot from your answer. I always love to learn new things, and this will come in very handy in the future, so thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You have to cast to call the right method.  It should never be a problem, you'll treat the return value very differently when you call the constructor.

Comment: @nobugz: See the updates of the OP below my answer: It seems the idea (and the problem with the implementation of said idea) is to store ways to clone an object, which might be methods (`ICloneable.Clone`) or constructors (copy constructor, above). The calling code shouldn't care, if I get it now, and the OP trie[sd] to find a way to treat both ways equally, as `MethodBase.Invoke()`.

Comment: Okay, then the *is* operator would work fine to detect that it actually a ConstructorInfo.

Comment: Sure, but I think the question is: How do I avoid doing a check to distinguish between normal MethodBase and a constructor and doing an if (constructor) { callConstructorInfo.Invoke } else { callMethodBase.Invoke } - which isn't possible imo. It can be wrapped in a different way (I suggested a Func<>), but it has to be treated differently, no matter what.

Comment: Benjamin got it right (see the "edit" section in my question). But thanks nonetheless, nobugz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the object is having a constructor like that, did you think about using this overload of [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) instead?

---

Update: So you have a cascading search for MethodInfo/MethodBase already and store them -> You don't want/cannot use `Activator`.

In that case I don't see a way to do what you want without a cast. But - maybe you could change the architecture to store a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>` and add those `Func<>` instances instead. Makes the calling code nicer (I assume) and would allow you to do this cast once:

```
// Constructor
dictionary.Add(type,
  source => ((ConstructorInfo) method).Invoke(new object[] {source})
);

// Clone
dictionary.Add(type,
  source => method.Invoke(source, new object[]{})
);
```

In fact, since you only care about the difference between constructor and normal method at the very site where you grab them, you wouldn't need a cast at all, would you?

```
// Constructor 2
dictionary.Add(type,
  source => yourConstructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] {source})
);
```

Unless I'm missing something (quite possible, of course) this could resolve the problem by doing this once on the defining side of the fence and the caller wouldn't need to mind if this is constructor or not?

---

One last time, then I'm going to stop the edit spam. I was bored and came up with the following code. Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

```
public class Cloner {
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> _cloneMap =
            new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();

    public T Clone<T>(T source) {
        Type sourceType = source.GetType();
        Func<object, object> cloneFunc;

        if (_cloneMap.TryGetValue(sourceType, out cloneFunc)) {
            return (T)cloneFunc(source);
        }

        if (TryGetCopyConstructorCloneFunc(sourceType, out cloneFunc)) {
            _cloneMap.Add(sourceType, cloneFunc);
            return (T)cloneFunc(source);
        }

        if (TryGetICloneableCloneFunc(sourceType, out cloneFunc)) {
            _cloneMap.Add(sourceType, cloneFunc);
            return (T)cloneFunc(source);
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    private bool TryGetCopyConstructorCloneFunc(Type type, 
                    out Func<object, object> cloneFunc) {
        var constructor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { type });
        if (constructor == null) {
            cloneFunc = source => null;
            return false;
        }
        cloneFunc = source => constructor.Invoke(new[] { source });
        return true;
    }

    private bool TryGetICloneableCloneFunc(Type type,
                    out Func<object, object> cloneFunc) {
        bool isICloneable = typeof(ICloneable).IsAssignableFrom(type);
        var cloneMethod = type.GetMethod("Clone", new Type[] { });
        if (!isICloneable || (cloneMethod == null)) {
            cloneFunc = source => null;
            return false;
        }
        cloneFunc = source => cloneMethod.Invoke(source, new object[] {});
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, it's more complicated than that. The actual method clone:
1. Looks up the dictionary I mentioned before to see if it already contains a method that will clone the object, to avoid having to look it up with reflection on each call to clone.
2. If the dictionary doesn't contain such a method, I look up the copy constructor as I show above. If I find it I add it to the dictionary and invoke it.
3. If I couldn't find a copy constructor, I see whether the object is ICloneable, and if so I get its Clone method, add it to the dictionary and invoke it.

Comment: ...So I don't really want to call Activator.CreateInstance in all cases. [NOTE: I had to put this in a different comment due to lack of space]

Comment: Better update the question with more details the next time and optionally give the poster(me) a heads-up "See updated post". More formatting options and no char limit.. :)

Comment: I know, that's what I've done in the past, but I had forgotten comments are so limited, and once I had posted it I couldn't delete it, so I had to leave it there. Now... check my question for an update ;)